# How can I make first column upper case?

Tags: regex, notepad++

How can I make all but the first column upper case?

like:

> e1a7ed4271d6aeaa49eb41a8aface3c312c274b4:543664034:101010

required output:

> E1A7ED4271D6AEAA49EB41A8AFACE3C312C274B4:543664034:101010

Comment: Hi, What do you mean by column? Even if you define the table as being colon separated, in your required output, you have converted the entire row to uppercase. Please provide a better example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notepad++ supports the `\U` (convert to upper-case) modifier in substitution, so you can use regular expression find and replace:

```
Find: ^([^:]+)
Replace: \U\1
```

Ensure you have selected the `Regular expression` radio button.